# What's the difference between this.example and this.$data.example to access "data" in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In vue.js, what's the difference between accessing data via `this.example` and `this.$data.example`?

What are the pros and cons for each approach, if any?

Here's an example using both.

JS:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      demo1: 'Test1',
      demo2: 'Test2',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    comp1() {
      return `value: ${this.demo1}`
    },
    comp2() {
      return `value: ${this.$data.demo2}`
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" v-model="demo1">
    <p>Result = <span v-html="demo1"></p>
    <p>Computed = <span v-html="comp1"></p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" v-model="$data.demo2">
    <p>Result = <span v-html="$data.demo2"></span></p>
    <p>Computed = <span v-html="comp2"></p>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The vue instance api has many properties that start with `$` that can be used in certain circumstances. For the `$data` property it might be useful to loop all data that exists on a particular component or maybe to send all of a components data to another component or api (think of a form component where each field is bound to a data property). For most use cases though it's more common to access data properties directly on the vue instance itself using `this.myDataProperty`. If you need to access a single property there is no benefit to using `this.$data` to access it though I'm not aware of any downside of doing so. Here's some additional reading about the vue instance and data properties in general from the Vue docs.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data